# undefined method `javascript_pack_tag' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000a730>

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I am currently working with webpacker currently shakapacker. The structure of my generated  app using `rails new react-app --webpack=react`is app/javascript/application.js and not as shown below

[image]

I have tried adding the `packs` folder manually. when I add `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react' %>` in `app/views/layouts/applcation.html.erb` it gives me this error

```
NoMethodError in Pages#index

Showing /home/gatwiri/react-app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

undefined method `javascript_packs_tag' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000ae60>
Did you mean?  javascript_path
```

controller generation

```
rails g controller pages index
```

/config/routes.rb

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#index'
end
```

NB: expected output `hello react`

What I have tried

using tag instead of tag_pack

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I downgraded my rails to rails 6.1.0 and restarted the project and everything worked okay